# viewDidLoad loads every time

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm doing a simple project, using firebase.

In my viewDidLoad fiction I'm creating an object of the class. I want to to be created only once during my work cycle. But, it creating a new objects every time i'm visiting this ViewController.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlArray = ["http://i.imgur.com/VAWlQ0S.gif", "http://i.imgur.com/JDzGqvE.gif", "http://67.media.tumblr.com/4cd2a04b60bb867bb4746d682aa60020/tumblr_mjs2dvWX6x1rvn6njo1_400.gif", "https://media.giphy.com/media/TlK63ELk5OPDzpb6Tao/giphy.gif", "http://i3.photobucket.com/albums/y90/spicestas/GeriHalliwell-Calling-new1.gif", "http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lnb9aozmM71qbxrlp.gif"]

    var counter = 1

    for url in urlArray {

       let nsUrl = NSURL(string: url)

       let girls = ProfileClass()

       girls.profilePhotoUrl = url
       girls.profileGender = "female"
       girls.profileName = "girlsname\(counter)"
       girls.profileSurname = "girlsurname\(counter)"
       girls.interest = "men"
       girls.uid = "\(randomStringWithLength(45))"

       counter++
       girls.SaveUser()


}
```

Maybe I should write my code in another function? Or the problem maybe be caused by my for loop?

Answer (score 3):

You should create another class that handles your data. Call it your data manager.

Make this a singleton, or make it a member of your app delegate, or whatever.

When you load the view controller in question, get the data from this object.

This is a nice little article on singletons in Swift

https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/

Comment: Here's a nice article on how not to become a singleton monster

 https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/singletons/

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to be executed only when the app is launched then move it inside the

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
```

of your AppDelegate.

This way it will be executed only when the user does launch your app.

> As *rigdonmr* said in the comments below, there are several techniques you can use when you want run a block of code only once. My answer instead  specifically tells you how to run a block of code once during **when the app is launched**.

Comment: this is not a general answer for how to execute something once in a view controller. This just says there is a place in the sdk where code will be executed once. The user wants the view controller to specifically call the functionality once

Comment: @rigdonmr: Are you sure the OP specifically needs to execute that code inside the `ViewController`? Because it said `I want it to be created only once during my work cycle`

Comment: Yeah but just don't want to convey the wrong idea that every time he wants to call something once in general he should resort to calling it in the app delegate.

Comment: @rigdonmr: correct, that's why I started by answer with this sentence: `If you want your code to be executed only when the app is launched`. Anyway I'm going to better explain this.